# Jquery file upload send call ajax without files

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I know at first that this can not make sense but, I got this scenario and i need a little help for figure out to the best with [JqueryFileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). Let's to exaplain:

After the registration of a user i have a page where the new user fill the form with him informations (Normal input file) And then, this form has even the possibility (not obligatory) to upload the profile image (doing it with ajax and in this case with JqueryFileUpload Plugin ). The problem is, if the user doesn't want upload the image, JqueryFileUplaod don't send the request because it hasn't file.

I thought to check if there is any file and if not, send the request with a normal request ajax. If this is the better way how can check if there is any file in it? Checking the value of the input file dons't work. `$('#fileupload').val()`

This is the code that i have for submit the request:

**HTML**

```
<!-- others fields -->

<div id="file-uploader" class="pull-left">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-def">Choose File</button>
      <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files" data-url="/profile/activate_profile">
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
// need to check if there is any image to upload if not 
// normal call ajax, if yes go next

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                return request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='_token']").attr('content'));
            },

            submit: function(e,data)
            {
               // add form vlues
                data.formData = {
                  'sport' : $('input[name="sport"]:checked').val(),
                  'city' :  $('#city').val(),
                  'country' : $('#form_location').val(),
                  '_token' : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                };
            },

            add: function (e, data) {

                data.context = $('[data-go="finish"]')
                    .click(function () {
                        $(this).attr('disabled',true);
                        data.submit();
                    });
            },
            done: function (e, data) {

                // do my stuff
            }

        });
```

Comment: You should probably use a plugin that attaches to a form rather than a file input, also does `$('#fileupload').val()` not give you the selected files' name?

Comment: No extacly the input file doesn't give me any name of selected file. But there is some way instead change plugin?

Comment: you can try `$('#fileupload')[0].files.length` but that wont work in old IE.

Comment: Mmmh that's true, i keep in touch this answer but i prefer have the the compatibility with old IE. Thanks i appreciate your help